# Convert string into json

Tags: php, regex, json

I have a string with timestamps (24h clock) and names of tv-shows, the format looks like this:

`21.45 Batman 23.30 The Hour 00.20 Newsfeed 04.00 Otherfeed 21.55 Soccer: USA - Spain 23.30 The Wire`

The string can be of any length, and i cannot modify the string in any way. I still want to use the string in a way that i need it as json. The string is always in the same format.

My goal is to convert the string to something like this:

```
{
  "shows": [
    {
        "show": "Batman",
        "time": "21.45"
    },
    {
        "show": "The Hour",
        "time": "23.30"
    },
    {
        "show": "Newsfeed",
        "time": "00.20"
    },
    {
        // etc...
    }
  ]
}
```

Im doing this with PHP and I really suck at regexp, its high on my learning list for 2014 :)

Comment: You should include your attempts in the question.

Comment: Splitting this string with regex would indeed be a good learning exercise. After that, you might want to look at the json_{encode,decode} functions.

Comment: have you tried `json_encode($your_string)`  ??

Comment: Sure, ill had some failed attempts with preg_split("#\\d+#", $string, -3, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

Comment: @PatrikStorm You know the rules :( Btw, there is no need to escape the backslash here. So `\d+` is fine. Here you go if you want something more fancy `(?P<time>\d+[.]\d+)\s*(?P<show>.*?)(?=\s*\d+[.]\d+|$)` [demo](http://regex101.com/r/tY9lC1). Take care

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$code = '21.45 Batman 23.30 The Hour 00.20 Newsfeed 04.00 Otherfeed 21.55 Soccer: USA - Spain 23.30 The Wire';

preg_match_all('~(?P<time>\d+[.]\d+)\s*(?P<show>.*?)(?=\s*\d+[.]\d+|$)~', $code, $codeSplit);

$shows = array();
for($i = 0; $i <= count($codeSplit['time']); $i++) {
    $shows[] = array('show' => $codeSplit['show'][$i], 'time' => $codeSplit['time'][$i]);
}

$json = json_encode(array('shows' => $shows));


var_dump($json);
```

Comment: Try something with `preg_match_all('~(?P<time>\d+[.]\d+)\s*(?P<show>.*?)(?=\s*\d+[.]\d+|$)~', $input, $m)`. Check `$m` :)

Comment: @HamZa the preg_match needs to be done on the string, not once the <time> and <show> is built.

Comment: If you have control over the text that the code can return, you can try serializing the string to list of objects right. you don't need to worry about regular expressions.

Comment: I have control over the returned data, but not the original string. Basically i could use underscores or join them...

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/94bb46954e40caf7f7a6edebf2b329781bc43f39

Comment: @zeflex lol I added `count()` in the loop to make it dynamic. See edit history :)

Comment: @HamZa sorry I added something to fix the fields name after your edit, I change that now :)

Comment: @zeflex PS. didn't know about the PHP sandbox site, its now a bookmark!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$string = '21.45 Batman 23.30 The Hour 00.20 Newsfeed 04.00 Otherfeed 21.55 Soccer: USA - Spain 23.30 The Wire';

$floatPattern = '/[-+]?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)/';

preg_match_all($floatPattern, $string, $numbers);
$numbers = $numbers[0];

$names = preg_split($floatPattern, $string);

$result = array();

foreach ($numbers as $k => $v) {
    $result[] = array('show' => $names[$k+1], 'time' => $v);
}

echo json_encode(array('shows' => $result));
```